# Expected number of steps in Gambler's ruin game with two players

Tags: probability, self-study, markov-process, random-walk

Let's say we have two players A and B. Player A has 3 coins and player B has 5 coins. If player wins the other player gives one coin. During game second player probability of loosing is $2/3$, while player A has chances of loosing 1/3. How to find expected number of steps (either outcome player A or B lose/win). Another condition is that players agrees to play maximum of 7 games.

Here is my attempt. My transition matrix

Q = $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $

$N = (I-Q)^{-1}$

$t = N1 =  \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{247}{85} & \frac{486}{85} & \frac{709}{85} & \frac{180}{17} & \frac{1027}{85} & \frac{1026}{85} & \frac{769}{85} 
\end{bmatrix}  $

But I am not sure if the answer is $\frac{1027}{85}$ since the players agree to play only 7 games maximum.